# can a design table be created -only- for colours in solidworks?

Tags: solidworks

exactly what the title says.  and, what is the easiest way of doing this?  I can do it clunky and manually by first creating a design table with only one dummy variable then adding the colour colums..

edit: this https://help.solidworks.com/2018/English/SolidWorks/sldworks/t_inserting_file_design_table.htm , with the correction that the A2 cell must be named "family", as described here (not where I originally found it) https://help.solidworks.com/2011/English/SolidWorks/sldworks/LegacyHelp/Sldworks/Configuration/Formatting_a_Design_Table.htm is what I was looking for..